# Mathieu equation and instabilities

Tags: mathematics, asymptotics

Consider the Mathieu equation
$$
\tag 1 y'' + (A -2q\cos(2t))y = 0,
$$
How does it provide instabilities for small $q << 1, A > q$? I don't understand this because as the result of adiabaticity Eq. $(1)$ admits WKB solution 
$$
y = \sum_{\pm}c_{\pm}\frac{\text{exp}\left(\pm i\int dt \omega (t)\right)}{\sqrt{\omega}}, \quad \omega^{2} \equiv A -2q\cos (2t) > 0, 
$$
which doesn't provide exponential growth. The queston arises because I don't understand how instabilities arise for preheating stage.

Comment: [Relevant paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1005.2196v1) (although it discusses the *quasi-periodic* Mathieu equation). I think the references in the paper can give further useful results.

Comment: "preheating stage" implies you are talking about some inflationary model (which would also explain the term "instability"). Please give more context, what exactly do you *mean* by "instability" here, and what has exponential growth or the Mathieu equation to do with it?